# Signing HTML Documents Using PGP or SSL via Web Forms

Tags: forms, ssl, lamp, identity, pgp

Let’s say I have a contract between two parties published on the Web. I want both parties to be able to sign the contract to show they consent to the terms, the way they would with handwriting in real life. I have seen many TOS agreements online where this is done with just a check box, but I want to go a step further and enable each party to assert that the signature is theirs and not a forgery (somebody else checking the box for them).

- Assuming the page is already served via HTTPS  and username/password combos are not an option, which cryptographic technology is best suited for identity validation: PGP, SSL, or something else?
- How might I do this using only HTML and a LAMP server on the other end, in such a way that the process is as automated as possible while still being secure? Code samples are obviously welcome but not necessary; I’m just trying to conceptualize it: do the contents of the contract have to be included in the signature? Do I have the users upload public keys or something? I’m no crypto expert so that’s where I get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is a transport security mechanism, it's not applicable.

You can use OpenPGP or you can use PKI (X.509 certificates and CMS format). These technologies let you sign the data twice or more times without invalidating previous signatures - this is done by using detached signatures.

The choice of what (PGP or PKI) to use is yours - these technologies can be used in similar scenarios, but have different ways to authenticate keys: in PGP user keys are signed by other users, while in PKI certificates are signed by certificate authorities, which is supposed to have more credibility.

When you "sign the document" using cryptographic signature, from technical point of view it's a hash of the document that is signed. The hash can be calculated on the server and sent to the client for signing, then the detached signature is transferred back to the server. So you can keep the document on the server, and private keys used for signing will not leave the client.

However, to do actual signing on the client, you need some module which will communicate with the server and do the job. You can't go with just a web browser - some browser plug-in is required. The reason is that Javascript "cryptography", even if it technically allowed access to client-side keys stored in files or on cryptographic devices, has certain conceptual flaws which make it almost useless. So you end up with using something more trusted and secure, i.e. signed applet or ActiveX control or Flash script.

Our company provides various security components, among which there are components and [modules for distributed signing](http://eldos.com/sbb/desc-dc.php) (including above mentioned plugins). These modules are for PKI operations (though in general we also have components for OpenPGP operations, these components don't support distributed signing at the moment).

And I should note, that "automation" here is possible to extent when the user chooses the certificate to use and clicks "sign" button (for example). You can't sign anything without user's explicit action. In some cases the user would also need to provide a PIN / password which protects a private key from being misused.

Comment: Oh, right, I conflated SSL and X.509 etc. because of OpenSSL…

So would it be possible then to hash the document when it also contains a form that needs filling out? Doesn't that change the document and invalidate any previous hash? Would it have to be a two-step process? Or would the document text have to be kept separate from the inputs?

Comment: @HughGuiney The answer depends on document format and signature format. For example, PDF offers a way to sign a document and leave form empty and fillable. At the same time PDF signature format doesn't let you sign the documents using two independent signatures. I agree that this is a big gap (or flaw) that prevents more widespread use of electronic signatures.

Comment: @HughGuiney So I can see only the following solution: one creates a pre-filled document without signing and puts both party names in it, then both parties sign it independently. An alternative would be to keep the private key on the server and when the user wants to make a signature, you generate a prefilled document, sign it on the fly with your key and then continue with user's signing.

Comment: (+1'ed already) @HughGuiney, besides the crypto aspect, doing this in a user-friendly way can be a challenge. Getting most users to understand how certs work and how to care for their private key is already quite difficult. Explaining where they get their cert from (and where it's stored, perhaps in the browser) and use of that from another application/applet can be confusing. Perhaps Eugene's products can help make the whole integration a bit smoother for the user (I haven't tried them).

Comment: @Bruno probably they don't make it much smoother, but they save the developer from developing client-server stuff and let him implement custom GUI for client modules in the way he chooses.